# Name for this kind of table saw?

Tags: powertools, terminology

I am finding pictures of table saws sold in England that are deeper than they are wide.  Does this kind of table saw shape have a particular name in the industry or among English remodeling contractors and woodworkers?

[image: narrow but deep British table saw]

Comment: A non cropped picture would be good. Maybe a reference model number or two as examples.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate:  Just to be clear, that's the picture I've found. If I had model numbers, I could contact the manufacturer.

Comment: The Brits are famously short on space (see also table saws that flip to become miter saws), so it might just be that the table on the saw you're picturing is tiny relative to the height needed to house a decent size motor and raising/lowering mechanism.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate The saw pictured doesn't offer wide rip capacity but not everyone needs to cut wide sheets. Compactness is more important for some. In the US full-size sheets of plywood are 4' x 8' and so manufacturers selling saws in the US tend to emphasize wide rip capacity. As saw size increases the first feature to become supersized is the rails: nowadays *all* so-called "contractor" saws and "hybrid" saws sold in the US come with very wide rails as standard; you simply cannot buy a saw without them. That's not how it used to be: in the past wide rails were an upgrade not standard.

Answer (score 3):

Portable table saw.

The one you have pictured is on the smaller size for the table.

Comment: Would that term distinguish it from "jobsite table saw" or are the two terms synonymous? The typical jobsite table saw/portable table saw in the US is wider than it is deep.

Comment: @mrblint   Would say close to synonymous, but I think "jobsite" was more of a brand/trade model name for saws, but now almost everyone calls those saws jobsite, but not every company can use that name in ads, only one.  Jobsite saws are portable saws, but not all portables are jobsite.